# login directly from .txt file in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on winform project. In my scene, I am saving `username` and `password` of user into `.txt` file named `credentials.txt` . now I want that, when I open my application first time, that means `credentials.txt` is blank. I have to enter username and password in login form. But when I close application and `login agian`, my `login form` should read username and password from .txt file and directly login with that. Not opening `login form`.

I have saved username and password in .txt file. But dont know how to perform next step.

My code for saving credentials in .txt file:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string Log_API = "http://api.retailbutton.co/WS/Service.php?Service=employeeLogin";
        if (LoginUser(Log_API))
        {
            logIn_Status = "true";
            GlolbalUtil.LogIn_Status = logIn_Status;
            this.Hide();

            string credentialPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\credentials\\credentials.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(credentialPath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("UserName :" + txtUsername.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Password :" + txtPassword.Text);
            }

            frmDash frmDash = new frmDash();
            frmDash.Owner = this;
            frmDash.Show();
            txtUsername.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
            //GlolbalUtil.accept_status = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Check Username and password");
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: find for a event where you can read the file and bind the relevant data to your relevant fields

Comment: i want to read file when my application starts. it starts with login form

Comment: fare, read the file.

Comment: yes i can read. then how to validate?

Comment: and sir how to read file after `:`

Comment: a trip to database to make sure the password is valid

Comment: i am not using database. its coming from web service

Comment: then assume it's valid

Comment: how to read after `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would suggest you to save username and password in a simpler way, so that reading from it should be easier.

```
writer.WriteLine(txtUsername.Text); 
writer.WriteLine(txtPassword.Text);
```

after saving like this on your login form loader:

```
var credentialLines = File.ReadAllLines(...your path...);
if(credentialLines.Any())
{
    var username = credentialLines[0];
    var password = credentialLines[1];

    /// Create an overload for your LoginUser method 
    /// so it can take credentails as parameteres
    if (LoginUser(Log_API, username, password))
    {
        logIn_Status = "true";
        GlolbalUtil.LogIn_Status = logIn_Status;
        //... other codes for authorization
        //... navigate to your main control maybe

        return;
    }        
}
LoginForm.Show();
```

That should do it.

**P.S.**
Saving user credentials in a plaintext format is not the best way to go for `remember me` purposes. Instead, first encrypt your username password tuple with a reliable encryption algorithm, then decrypt it while reading from it. This should be handled really carefully while working with users credentials.

Comment: its not entering into `if(!credentialLines.Any())`

Comment: its displays data while debugging but not entering into it

Comment: I have made a mistake, there shouldn't be `!` before the `Any()`. I've edited the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

before navigating to login form, you need to read the .txt file, validate the credentials and if successfully validated,navigate to main page else navigate to login page again.
you can use the below code to read a file

```
  string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"your file location");
```

Comment: This is not an answar.

Comment: ya but as you can see, i have saved my username and password as Username : txtUsername.text and Password: txtPassword.text